# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) in fulltext search

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT * FROM POST WHERE ID IN 
    (SELECT ID, MATCH(TITLE, CONTENT) AGAINST ('something lalala') AS score 
    FROM POST_SHADOW WHERE MATCH(TITLE, CONTENT) AGAINST ('something lalala') 
    ORDER BY score DESC)
```

so subquery give me 2 column (ID and score) what causes problem.
I dont know how remove score's column with not removing order of showing record.

Comment: no... its not duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to show the post according to the score of post_shadow table whose id column is associated with post id you can rewrite your query using join as below

```
SELECT 
  p.* 
FROM
  POST 
  JOIN POST_SHADOW ps 
    ON (p.ID = ps.ID) 
WHERE MATCH(ps.TITLE, ps.CONTENT) AGAINST ('something lalala') 
ORDER BY MATCH(ps.TITLE, ps.CONTENT) AGAINST ('something lalala') DESC
```

You can use the whole expression in order by clause to order your results accordingly if there is one-to-many relation b/w post and post_shadow then change your select part to `SELECT DISTINCT  p.* ...`